# Discord.py for user in bot.user.friends: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'friends'

Tags: discord.py

```
def DM():
        message1 = input("What to send? >> ")
        for user in bot.user.friends:
            user.send(f'{message1}')
            print(f'[+] Sent Message to {user}')
        if discord.Forbidden:
            print(f"[-] Couldn't send message to {user}")
            pass
    DM()    

bot.run(token, bot = False)
```

This is my code, but the error im getting is:
for user in bot.user.friends:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'friends'

Comment: This is no longer possible in 2.0: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html?highlight=friends#removal-of-support-for-user-accounts. Downgrade to 1.7.3 if you want to use this (be aware that it violates terms of service).

Answer (score 0):

Self bot is against the Discord Terms of Service

and discord.py also remove the self bot features

so there is no way you can do that with discord.py

(there is some other package can do that, but that can cause your account got delete)

(and if you decide to against the rule, and use other package, you can use while true not just call the function again in the function.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).